# Zeek logs to elk

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk, zeek

I've installed elk on server and zeek with filebeat on another server.
I followed documnetation to install each one, but the filebeat is not shipping zeek logs to kibana.
by the way filebeat basic logs is shiped to kibana but without zeek logs
for the records:
1 - I've enabled zeek module
2 - I've add load policy/tuning/json-logs.zeek to local.zeek

Comment: what version of Filebeat? what do the Filebeat logs show?

Comment: Thanks for replying, problem solved.
firewall blocked port 5601 on zeek server. even i added this port to the firewall.